# Blank Map in android studio app, app released two months ago and now stop work

Tags: api, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-android-api-2

I released an app two months ago with Gmaps service and it worked properly but from some days the app stopped doing its job! Now the map appears totally blank and I don't know what do... I tried to recompile and control api key but everything is ok! So when I compile now an error appears:

```
05-23 15:43:00.389 13762-13762/vs.realitycompany W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/vs.realitycompany-1/lib/arm
05-23 15:43:00.548 13762-13762/vs.realitycompany I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up, version: 8487
05-23 15:43:00.548 13762-13762/vs.realitycompany I/GMPM: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.GMPM VERBOSE
05-23 15:43:00.560 13762-13762/vs.realitycompany E/GMPM: GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.
05-23 15:43:00.560 13762-13762/vs.realitycompany E/GMPM: Scheduler not set. Not logging error/warn.
05-23 15:43:00.617 13762-14730/vs.realitycompany E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
05-23 15:43:00.938 13762-14738/vs.realitycompany D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
05-23 15:43:00.981 13762-14738/vs.realitycompany I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: Nondeterministic_AU_msm8974_LA.BF.1.1.3_RB1__release_AU (Ia6c73e7530)
                                                               OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.29.00.00
                                                               Build Date: 12/04/15 Fri
                                                               Local Branch: mybranch17080070
                                                               Remote Branch: quic/LA.BF.1.1.3_rb1.5
                                                               Local Patches: NONE
                                                               Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
05-23 15:43:00.982 13762-14738/vs.realitycompany I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-23 15:43:03.759 13762-13762/vs.realitycompany I/zzad: Making Creator dynamically
05-23 15:43:03.793 13762-13762/vs.realitycompany D/ChimeraCfgMgr: Reading stored module config
05-23 15:43:03.817 13762-13762/vs.realitycompany W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000001/n/armeabi-v7a
05-23 15:43:03.817 13762-13762/vs.realitycompany W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000001/n/armeabi
05-23 15:43:03.818 13762-13762/vs.realitycompany D/ChimeraFileApk: Primary ABI of requesting process is armeabi-v7a
05-23 15:43:03.819 13762-13762/vs.realitycompany D/ChimeraFileApk: Classloading successful. Optimized code found.
05-23 15:43:03.853 13762-13762/vs.realitycompany I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 8487000
05-23 15:43:03.859 13762-13762/vs.realitycompany I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 9083438
05-23 15:43:04.202 13762-13762/vs.realitycompany I/Choreographer: Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-23 15:43:04.222 13762-14843/vs.realitycompany I/b: Sending API token request.
05-23 15:43:04.484 13762-14843/vs.realitycompany E/b: Authentication failed on the server.
05-23 15:43:04.484 13762-14843/vs.realitycompany E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
05-23 15:43:04.485 13762-14843/vs.realitycompany E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
                                                                            Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
                                                                            Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
                                                                                API Key: AIzaSyCPsPVsNjqAizEyBzu1w8_6EGlZHKfSAbQ
                                                                                Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): 38:10:51:0C:63:CA:8E:34:84:EE:E5:9B:4F:72:AF:61:8A:5A:E3:15;vs.realitycompany
05-23 15:43:06.176 13762-14839/vs.realitycompany V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: com.google.android.gms signature not valid.  Found: 
                                                                            MIIEQzCCAyugAwIBAgIJAMLgh0ZkSjCNMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBAUAMHQxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRMw
                                                                            EQYDVQQIEwpDYWxpZm9ybmlhMRYwFAYDVQQHEw1Nb3VudGFpbiBWaWV3MRQwEgYDVQQKEwtHb29n
                                                                            bGUgSW5jLjEQMA4GA1UECxMHQW5kcm9pZDEQMA4GA1UEAxMHQW5kcm9pZDAeFw0wODA4MjEyMzEz
                                                                            MzRaFw0zNjAxMDcyMzEzMzRaMHQxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRMwEQYDVQQIEwpDYWxpZm9ybmlhMRYw
                                                                            FAYDVQQHEw1Nb3VudGFpbiBWaWV3MRQwEgYDVQQKEwtHb29nbGUgSW5jLjEQMA4GA1UECxMHQW5k
                                                                            cm9pZDEQMA4GA1UEAxMHQW5kcm9pZDCCASAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggENADCCAQgCggEBAKtW
                                                                            LgDYO6IIrgqWbxJOKdoR8qtW0I9Y4sypEwPpt1TTcvZApxsdyxMJZ2JORland2qSGT2y5b+3JKke
                                                                            dxiLDmpHpDsz2WCbdxgxRczfey5YZnTJ4VZbH0xqWVW/8lGmPav5xVwnIiJS6HXk+BVKZF+JcWjA
                                                                            sb/GEuq/eFdpuzSqeYTcfi6idkyugwfYwXFU1+5fZKUaRKYCwkkFQVfcAs1fXA5V+++FGfvjJ/Cx
                                                                            URaSxaBvGdGDhfXE28LWuT9ozCl5xw4Yq5OGazvV24mZVSoOO0yZ31j7kYvtwYK6NeADwbSxDdJE
                                                                            qO4k//0zOHKrUiGYXtqw/A0LFFtqoZKFjnkCAQOjgdkwgdYwHQYDVR0OBBYEFMd9jMIhF1Ylmn/T
                                                                            gt9r45jk14alMIGmBgNVHSMEgZ4wgZuAFMd9jMIhF1Ylmn/Tgt9r45jk14aloXikdjB0MQswCQYD
                                                                            VQQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UECBMKQ2FsaWZvcm5pYTEWMBQGA1UEBxMNTW91bnRhaW4gVmlldzEUMBIG
                                                                            A1UEChMLR29vZ2xlIEluYy4xEDAOBgNVBAsTB0FuZHJvaWQxEDAOBgNVBAMTB0FuZHJvaWSCCQDC
                                                                            4IdGZEowjTAMBgNVHRMEBTADAQH/MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBAUAA4IBAQBt0lLO74UwLDYKqs6Tm8/y
                                                                            zKkEu116FmH4rkaymUIE0P9KaMftGlMexFlaYjzmB2OxZyl6euNXEsQH8gjwyxCUKRJNexBiGcCE
                                                                            yj6z+a1fuHHvkiaai+KL8W1EyNmgjmyy8AW7P+LLlkR+ho5zEHatRbM/YAnqGcFh5iZBqpknHf1S
                                                                            KMXFh4dd239FJ1jWYfbMDMy3NS5CTMQ2XFI1MvcyUTdZPErjQfTbQe3aDQsQcafEQPD+nqActifK
                                                                            Z0Np0IS9L9kR/wbNvyz6ENwPiTrjV2KRkEjH78ZMcUQXg0L3BYHJ3lc69Vs5Ddf9uUGGMYldX3Wf
                                                                            MBEmh/9iFBDAaTCK
05-23 15:43:06.195 13762-14839/vs.realitycompany E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates.ModuleDescriptor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/vs.realitycompany-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/vs.realitycompany-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
05-23 15:43:06.201 13762-14839/vs.realitycompany I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:1
05-23 15:43:06.201 13762-14839/vs.realitycompany I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 1
05-23 15:43:06.212 13762-14839/vs.realitycompany W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000000/n/armeabi
05-23 15:43:06.213 13762-14839/vs.realitycompany D/ChimeraFileApk: Primary ABI of requesting process is armeabi-v7a
05-23 15:43:06.215 13762-14839/vs.realitycompany D/ChimeraFileApk: Classloading successful. Optimized code found.
05-23 15:43:06.219 13762-14839/vs.realitycompany D/GoogleCertificates: com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates module is loaded
05-23 15:43:06.298 13762-14839/vs.realitycompany D/GoogleCertificatesImpl: Fetched 154 Google release certificates
05-23 15:43:06.304 13762-14839/vs.realitycompany V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: vs.realitycompany signature not valid.  Found: 
                                                                            MIIB3TCCAUYCAQEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwNzEWMBQGA1UEAwwNQW5kcm9pZCBEZWJ1ZzEQMA4G
                                                                            A1UECgwHQW5kcm9pZDELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMwHhcNMTYwNTIyMjAyNzM5WhcNNDYwNTE1MjAyNzM5
                                                                            WjA3MRYwFAYDVQQDDA1BbmRyb2lkIERlYnVnMRAwDgYDVQQKDAdBbmRyb2lkMQswCQYDVQQGEwJV
                                                                            UzCBnzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOBjQAwgYkCgYEAj+2RpluWlva2H85SRcYtZX7E4dQY/GSAgdEs
                                                                            OaaZLP8yzPo0OOaGUdNz+ZI1uY7CaAX9i+EsOsUZXA0St9w7u7jUpAnt3DSBOLCjH+m/fc3QErBr
                                                                            c3aDBQ7e34fzMr22d7grgIfe4Lje33qASiuAOYcs25wF8fK19qsFFrkkW/kCAwEAATANBgkqhkiG
                                                                            9w0BAQUFAAOBgQAYPncLTg3aEIZVs94qrk+QiuugbBWrHcHDf68/fZvCZW0JIeYnCRo4KOHjSWzR
                                                                            Ppv8DduDZUZs6rIK4Bo+MLts/G+5DqlV60tDAd8vUO0YEWKtTeiY4oIY5QE1TnVDPILBcy2OCBCP
                                                                            6I7lG7DiJC3s+xuGx07HxV57j2TGtxlQ7w==
05-23 15:43:06.304 13762-14839/vs.realitycompany D/GoogleCertificatesImpl: Fetched 300 Google certificates
05-23 15:43:06.313 13762-14839/vs.realitycompany V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: vs.realitycompany signature not valid.  Found: 
                                                                            MIIB3TCCAUYCAQEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwNzEWMBQGA1UEAwwNQW5kcm9pZCBEZWJ1ZzEQMA4G
                                                                            A1UECgwHQW5kcm9pZDELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMwHhcNMTYwNTIyMjAyNzM5WhcNNDYwNTE1MjAyNzM5
                                                                            WjA3MRYwFAYDVQQDDA1BbmRyb2lkIERlYnVnMRAwDgYDVQQKDAdBbmRyb2lkMQswCQYDVQQGEwJV
                                                                            UzCBnzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOBjQAwgYkCgYEAj+2RpluWlva2H85SRcYtZX7E4dQY/GSAgdEs
                                                                            OaaZLP8yzPo0OOaGUdNz+ZI1uY7CaAX9i+EsOsUZXA0St9w7u7jUpAnt3DSBOLCjH+m/fc3QErBr
                                                                            c3aDBQ7e34fzMr22d7grgIfe4Lje33qASiuAOYcs25wF8fK19qsFFrkkW/kCAwEAATANBgkqhkiG
                                                                            9w0BAQUFAAOBgQAYPncLTg3aEIZVs94qrk+QiuugbBWrHcHDf68/fZvCZW0JIeYnCRo4KOHjSWzR
                                                                            Ppv8DduDZUZs6rIK4Bo+MLts/G+5DqlV60tDAd8vUO0YEWKtTeiY4oIY5QE1TnVDPILBcy2OCBCP
                                                                            6I7lG7DiJC3s+xuGx07HxV57j2TGtxlQ7w==
```

What I can do?
Only last thing, I've noticed that there isn't a google_maps_api.xml for release (there is only for debug). Could the issue be arising from missing google_maps_api.xml? What can be the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I read through your error logs and found some issue like:

***The application may be doing too much work on its main thread*** - what this means is that your code is taking long to process.

Fixing this requires identifying nodes where there is or possible can happen long duration of process. The best way is to do all the processing no matter how small or big in a thread separate from main [UI thread](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html).

***Sending API token request Authentication failed on the server***

Don't forgot to enable the map services in google console. Try uninstalling and reinstalling the application. Apparently if you make one mistake on the configuration the system caches the failed authentication and your maps won't work even after fixing your configuration.

Try [following the docs and guides](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start#step_1_download_android_studio) on configuring Google Maps API on Android but every time you change something on your configuration uninstall and reinstall. Ensure that the ["Google Maps Android API"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/) is enabled and ensure that the following Android Key exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
05-23 15:43:03.853 13762-13762/vs.realitycompany I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 8487000
05-23 15:43:03.859 13762-13762/vs.realitycompany I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 9083438
```

These two lines indicate the current Google Play Service on the device is older than what you used, so it won't show any map.
check your developer console, and see if the api token is at the right place and nothing changed !